# Apple's Core Telephony Public or Private

Tags: ios, ios9, core-telephony

Is there any official source saying CoreTelephony is a private framework and can not be used if we want to upload app on App store.
Or, is there any part of it that can be used as a usual public API.

Comment: Why should it be private? You can simply use the `CTCallCenter` for example!

Comment: If it's documented it's most probably not private ;)

Answer (score 1):

Core telephony framework is not fully private (As far as I know, correct me if I'm wrong). You can use several classes from [Core Telephony](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/) frame work, such as:

- [CTCall](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CTCall)
- [CTCallCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CTCallCenter)
- [CTCarrier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CTCarrier)
- [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo)